# Adomdclient for dotnet core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, adomd.net

I am using the unofficial ADOMD client

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClientNetCore/

It looks fine in my project that target dotnet core 3.1. However, it keeps on returning error when I use it on project that is targeting dotnet core 2.2.

The error received is "The operation was canceled."

Is it unsupported for dotnet core 2.2? Ia there anyway to make it works on dotnet core 2.2?

Answer (score 2):

Since your question was posted, an officially maintained ADOMD.NET (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient) for .NET Core is [available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64/) in preview on nuget. You can consider using this library instead of the unofficial library.

Comment: you mean it support Tabular model only but not multidimensional cube?

Comment: @Ppp no. On prem not supported (tabular or multidimensional at the moment). Only cloud. At least that’s my understanding of the preview limitation.

Comment: I believe by now on prem is also supported